# Calling function from file(1). Try to use variable from 'Entry' input of file(2). end up still got file(1) variable

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, import

Sorry for the title. I'm not sure how to make it proper for this.

I am scraping website. Most parts are done and now I try to create input fields with TKinter.
Using file `Button.py` to call a function from file `Bitkub_scrape.py`. Function `make_df()` needs value of `file_path` in order to work.

I want to use the input of `Entry` field in `Button.py` file.
It returns:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

in which `''` is from `Bitkub_scrape.py`.

Here is my function code in 'Bitkub_scrape.py` file:

```
def make_df():
    #for loop make list
    for coin, chains, wdf in zip(coin_name_res, chain_name, fee_res):
        #print("Coin name: {} Chain: {} Fee: {}".format(coin, chains, wdf))

        #create dataframe
        df=(pd.DataFrame({'coin_name': coin_name_res[0:100], 'chain_name': chain_name, 'withdrawal_fees':fee_res}))
        #print(df)
        file_path = ""
        #csv
        df.to_csv(file_path, index=False)
        df_saved_file = pd.read_csv(file_path)
        df_saved_file

    driver.quit()

make_df()
```

And here is my `Button.py` file:

```
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title('Bitkub Fee monitor')
root.geometry("500x500")

e = Entry(root, width=60)
e.pack()

def Bitkub():
    from Bitkub_scrape import make_df
    make_df()
    file_path.append(e.get())
    Bitkub_label = Label(root,text="Done, Check file name: Bitkub_fee.csv")
    Bitkub_label.pack()
    print(path)


Bitkub_button = Button(root,text="Get Bitkub Fee", command=Bitkub, height = 5, width = 60, bg="green")
Bitkub_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Pass the current contents of the `Entry` field to `make_df()` as an argument. i.e. `make_df(e.get())`.

Comment: Thank you for helping me improve the question. Which file do I have to fix an argument? I've tried, still not working. maybe I missed something.

Comment: You would have to change both — because the `make_df()` function itself will also need to be changed to accept the argument it will now be passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to implement what I suggested in a comment — passing the `Entry`'s contents to the `make_df()` function — which requires changes to both source files. Note the below is untested.

`Button.py` file changes:

```
from Bitkub_scrape import make_df
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Bitkub Fee monitor')
root.geometry("500x500")

e = tk.Entry(root, width=60)
e.pack()

def Bitkub():
    make_df(e.get())
    Bitkub_label = Label(root, text="Done, Check file name: Bitkub_fee.csv")
    Bitkub_label.pack()
    print(path)


Bitkub_button = tk.Button(root, text="Get Bitkub Fee", command=Bitkub, height=5, width=60,
                          bg="green")
Bitkub_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

`Bitkub_scrape.py` file changes:

```
import pandas as pd

def make_df(file_path):
    for coin, chains, wdf in zip(coin_name_res, chain_name, fee_res):
        #print("Coin name: {} Chain: {} Fee: {}".format(coin, chains, wdf))

        # Create dataframe
        df=(pd.DataFrame({'coin_name': coin_name_res[0:100], 'chain_name': chain_name,
                          'withdrawal_fees':fee_res}))
        #print(df)
        # Create CSV file
        df.to_csv(file_path, index=False)
        df_saved_file = pd.read_csv(file_path)
        df_saved_file

    driver.quit()
```

Also delete the `make_df()` call at the end of the file.

Comment: The result is `TypeError: make_df() missing 1 required positional argument: 'file_path'` It take an argument from `Bitkub_scrape.py`

Comment: That sounds like you didn't remove the call to it  with no argument that was at the very end of the `Button.py` file. This needs to be deleted.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I got it. The problem was the call in `Bitkub_scrape.py` as you mentioned.

Comment: That's good to hear. Apologies for not making the changes clearer to begin with. This misunderstanding also reinforces my aversion to posting answers with code in them that I can't test — the reason I initially only posted a comment describing what to do.